# Running Junit test from command line

Tags: java, unit-testing, command-line, junit, hamcrest

So I wrote a class called `Item` and using Junit wrote a test called `ItemTest` and I want to execute my test from a command line. This is steps that I followed:

1. set the path, to run java.exe and set the classpath to libraries

   ```
   ...> set path="C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_40\bin"
   ...> set classpath=C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\hamcrest-core-1.3.jar; C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\junit-4.11.jar
   ```
2. then i simply run org.junit.runner.JUnitCore to see if added libs were in classpath

   ```
   ...>java org.junit.runner.JUnitCore
   ```

   the output was

   ```
   JUnit version 4.11
   Time: 0,001
   OK (0 tests)
   ```
3. Then I compiled without an error `Item` and `ItemTest`

   ```
   C:\Users\User\IdeaProjects\My_project\src>javac .\main\java\Item.java .\test\java\ItemTest.java
   ```
4. Then try ro run this classes

   ```
   C:\Users\User\IdeaProjects\My_project\src>java org.junit.runner.JUnitCore main.java.Item test.java.ItemTest
   ```
5. In the end I got this

   ```
   JUnit version 4.11
   Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: main/java/Item (wrong name: Item)
   at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
   at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:792)
   at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:14 2)
   at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)
   at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
   at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
   at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
   at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
   at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
   at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
   at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
   at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:190)
   at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.runMain(JUnitCore.java:86)
   at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.runMainAndExit(JUnitCore.java:47)
   at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.main(JUnitCore.java:40)
   ```

   How to fix this ? Should I put `Item`in classpath ?

**UPD#1**

Put this path in my classpath doesn't work (with and without `src`):

```
    C:\Users\User\IdeaProjects\My_project\src>
```

**UPD#2**

When I want to run the class I adress to him as he stores in file system or in what packages he lays ? Because I don't have packages and so `My_project` apart from being project name is a module name.

**SOLVED**

This is the way - I add to classpath next paths:

1. The path to class `Item`:

   ```
   C:\Users\User\IdeaProjects\My_project\src\main\java\;
   ```
2. The path to test class `ItemTest`:

   ```
   C:\Users\User\IdeaProjects\My_project\src\test\java\;
   ```
3. Then simply run:

   ```
   ...>java org.junit.runner.JUnitCore ItemTest
   ```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to put the location of the .class files in the classpath. Even if you are in the same folder it won't find them if they are not in the classpath. That comes from DOS x .... anyone else.

In DOS the OS looks first in the current folder. Everywhere else the OS looks first in the path (or classpath for Java).

If Item is in the package com.example.Item and the class is in c:\users\test\myproj\target\com\example\Item.class then you must add c:\users\test\myproj\target\ to the classpath

Comment: do I have a problem if in "project structure" dialog I have "My_project" as project name and also as module name ? And could you help me understand "Project compiler output" path does somehow relevant to my problem ?

Comment: that sounds like Maven. No, you don't have a problem. You can have any folder name and any module name, as long as you reference them properly.